# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 00923. can some one help where I am making the mistake

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

my query as follows.
I am getting error as

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 5 Column: 15

can someone help where I  have made mistake

```
SELECT a.execution_count ,

OBJECT_NAME(objectid) Name,

query_text = SUBSTRING( 

b.text, 
a.statement_start_offset/2, 

( CASE WHEN a.statement_end_offset = -1 

THEN len(convert(nvarchar(max), b.text)) * 2 

ELSE a.statement_end_offset 

END - a.statement_start_offset)/2

) ,

b.dbid ,

dbname = db_name(b.dbid) ,

b.objectid ,

a.creation_time,
a.last_execution_time,

a.*

FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats a 

CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) as b 

WHERE OBJECT_NAME(objectid) = 'YOURPROCEDURE'

ORDER BY a.last_execution_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
query_text = SUBSTRING( 

b.text, 
a.statement_start_offset/2, 

( CASE WHEN a.statement_end_offset = -1 

THEN len(convert(nvarchar(max), b.text)) * 2 

ELSE a.statement_end_offset 

END - a.statement_start_offset)/2

) ,
```

must be:

```
SUBSTRING( 

b.text, 
a.statement_start_offset/2, 

( CASE WHEN a.statement_end_offset = -1 

THEN len(convert(nvarchar(max), b.text)) * 2 

ELSE a.statement_end_offset 

END - a.statement_start_offset)/2

) as query_text,
```

same here:

```
dbname = db_name(b.dbid) ,
```

must be

```
db_name(b.dbid) dbname,
```

Comment: it says ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 33 Column: 10

Comment: Which line is line 33?

Comment: CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) as b

Comment: can you use an inner join instead of cross apply?

Comment: even Inner join also gives the same error, may be we are missing something else

Comment: realy the same error? Have you also added the on clause?

Comment: No I didn't add

Comment: @Yoga do it please

Comment: @Yoga, can you create en sqlfiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in the query like putting equal sign. Please see below:

```
SELECT a.execution_count, 
       a.OBJECT_NAME (objectid) Name, 
       SUBSTR( b.text, a.statement_start_offset/2,( CASE WHEN a.statement_end_offset = -1
                                                    THEN len(convert(nvarchar(max), b.text)) * 2
                                                    ELSE a.statement_end_offset
                                                    END - a.statement_start_offset)/2) as query_text ,

       b.dbid ,
       db_name(b.dbid) dbname,
       b.objectid ,
       a.creation_time,
       a.last_execution_time,
       a.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
CROSS JOIN sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) as b
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(objectid) = 'YOURPROCEDURE'
ORDER BY a.last_execution_time DESC ;
```

Cross apply will work in Oracle 12c onwards. Please tag your proper db.